# Can we run ASP.NET MVC 2.0 on .Net 2.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dynamic-data

I have an asp.net website which is already developed in .net 3.5, Now I asked to develop few pages in MVC 2.0 and few pages in DynamicData. Now Can I Run the ASP.NET MVC 2.0 and Dynamic Data in 3.5. When I run this i am getting lot of errors in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

No, I dont think so.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 2.0 requires .NET 3.5. You cannot run it on .NET 2.0 only.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.asp.net/mvc/whatisaspmvc/.